# ROS Answers SE migration: rosws problem

Tags: ros, rosws, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i'm a beginner and i just installed ubuntu and ros...... I successfully installed ROS and while setting up workspace i'm getting error messages stating that rosws: command not found while setting up the overlay....please help.........

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41169/rosws-problem/) by [Vishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3010/vishnu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2